# Is the loss printed by tensorflow a batch/sample wise loss or is it a running average loss?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

When I train a TensorFlow model, it usually prints information similar to the below line at each iteration

`INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.9433185, step = 11 (0.300 sec)`

Is the loss being printed the loss of the batch that the model saw currently, or is it the running average loss over all the previous batches of the training?

If I use a batch size of 1 i.e. only one training sample in each batch, then the loss printed will be of every sample separately, or will it be a running average loss?

Answer (score 3):

The loss reported in the progress bar of Keras/TensorFlow is always a running mean of the batches seen so far, it is not a per-batch value.

I do not think there is a way to see the per-batch values during training.

Answer (score 1):

@Dr. Snoopy is right, but if you are looking for more support, here it is.

In the TF documentation for `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback)), the description of the `logs` parameter (for e.g. the `on_train_batch_end` method), which can be used to obtain the loss, states "Aggregated metric results up until this batch." So it is reasonable to believe that the loss is a mean over all batches seen so far in the epoch.

Furthermore, in [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_your_own_callbacks), the authors print the loss at every batch and call it an average up to that batch, like "Up to batch 4, the average loss is  213.47."

Hope that helps. I wish the TF documentation was a bit more clear on this. I had the same question as you, as I am trying to get the per-batch or even per-sample loss during training, but have not yet found a good solution.